# DynamicVariable not working with Future

Tags: scala

The following code:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util.DynamicVariable
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val a = new DynamicVariable(1)
    a.withValue(2) {
      println(a.value)
      Await.result(Future(println(a.value)), Duration.Inf)
    }
  }
}
```

is printing:

```
2
1
```

But DynamicVariable is relying on `InheritableThreadLocal` which says in the doc:

> This class extends ThreadLocal to provide inheritance of
>   values from parent thread to child thread: when a child thread is
>   created, the child receives initial values for all inheritable
>   thread-local variables for which the parent has values.

Does this means InheritableThreadLocal is actually not working?

Comment: Just tested it as a script and as compiled with `scalac` in 2.12.4. It's printing "2 2" on two lines, repeatedly.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Maybe it's OS dependent. I'm running on a Mac OS. What os are you using?

Comment: Indeed on Scastie it works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8GPourStSV2mJfjbWr5jnw

Comment: On Scastie it does not always work. Run few times in a row and you will see.

Comment: So this is interesting because my original issue is with `Console.withOut(){}`. See https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jfu7mUdoR2KZqwowIutALQ We can see that it display `Hello future` sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the article that made things work:
http://stevenskelton.ca/threadlocal-variables-scala-futures/

Basically we need to implement a custom `ForkJoinPool` where we copy values of DynamicVariables. It's not very nice workaround but it works.

You guys are right in the comments and answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Probably I am not correct, but it looks to me that in your example there's no parent/child relationships between 2 threads which are involved.

The thread running your `Future` is one of the threads from imported `global` execution context. I think this execution context is created before the thunk in the second argument to `withValue` starts to be executed.

So the excerpt from the documentation you have provided probably is not applicable in this case.

Correct me if I am wrong, since I would also like to understand the dynamic variables concept better.

Comment: This is correct. The OP can provide the `ExecutionContext` to the `Future`, and bind the `ExecutionContext` to spawn from the current thread. However, `DynamicVariable`s are not a good fit for the problem if you have to muck around like that.

Answer (score 1):

Another guess:

TL;DR: `Future.apply{...}` does not spawn a child thread, it works with whatever thread it gets from the implicit execution context, in this case `global`.

---

What happens in your case:

- You create the dynamic variable `a` with initial value 1
- Your `main` and `a.withValue(2) { println(a.value)` are executed on some thread T1, which now has `a.value` stack `[1, 2]`.
- When you call `Future.apply{println(a.value)}`, your `global` execution context *happens* to give you another thread `T2` with stack `[1]`.
- You get output `2` from `T1` and `1` from `T2`

What happens on Scastie / my lightweight setup here:

- Dynamic variable `a` with `[1]` on stack is created
- `a.withValue(2) { println(a.value); ... }` is run on some thread `T1`, which now has stack `[1, 2]`.
- My `global` execution context for some reason runs `Future.apply` *on the same thread* `T1`
- Therefore, the `Future.apply{println(a.value)}` takes the value `2` from the top of the stack `[1,2]` of the same Thread `T1`
- I get output "2 2"

To summarize:

- if the threads are "abundant" and you happen to get different threads `T1` and `T2` from the execution context, you get output "2 1".
- if the threads are "scarce" (as on online Scastie interpreter) and you happen to get the same `T1` in `Future.apply` that already runs your `main`, then you get "2 2"

Is this plausible?