# Scala Dynamic Variable problem with Akka-Http asynchronous requests

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

My application is using Akka-Http to handle requests. I would like to somehow pass incoming extracted request context (fe. token) from routes down to other methods calls without explicitly passing them (because that would require modyfing a lot of code).

I tried using Dynamic Variable to handle this but it seems to not work as intended.

Example how I used and tested this:

- object holding Dynamic Variable instance:

```
object TestDynamicContext  {
  val dynamicContext = new DynamicVariable[String]("")
}
```

- routes wrapper for extracting and setting request context (token)

```
private def wrapper: Directive0 = {
  Directive { routes => ctx =>
     val newValue = UUID.randomUUID().toString
     
     TestDynamicContext.dynamicContext.withValue(newValue) {
       routes(())(ctx)
     }
}
```

I expected to all calls of TestDynamicContext.dynamicContext.value for single request under my wrapper to return same value defined in said wrapper but thats not the case. I verified this by generating for each request separate UUID and passing it explicitly down the method calls - but for single request TestDynamicContext.dynamicContext.value sometimes returns different values.

I think its worth mentioning that some operations underneath use Futures and I though that this may be the issue but solution proposed in this thread did not solve this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49256600/16511727.

If somebody has any suggestions how to handle this (not necessarily using Dynamic Variable) I would be very grateful.